# How to read dirty csv file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very dirty data that I need to read in Python. The csv file seperated with comma, but there are also some commas in the first column of my data that puts me in a tight position. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'reportname':['column1,column2, column3, column4', 
                      'some...texts, are here with commas, www.facebook.com, 2000, 150', 
                      'some-texts_again_here, www.twitter.com, 1000, 50']}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

However, it does not match the data in correct columns since there is comma inside some of the rows of the first column. Here is my desired data:

```
desired_data = {'column1':['some...texts, are here with commas', 'some-texts_again_here'],
        'column2':['www.facebook.com', 'www.twitter.com'],
        'column3':[2000, 1000],
        'column4':[150, 50]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(desired_data)
```

Is there a way to read the csv file accurately?

Comment: In the raw text file are the fields with commas surrounded by quotes?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski no, they are not.

Comment: If there are never any commas in the other columns you can do `line.rsplit(',', number_of_columns - 1)` This works because `rsplit()` splits from the right side. The second argument constrains the number of splits that can be made.

Comment: Sorry, I am very beginner at Python. Where to put it? @StevenRumbalski

Answer (score 2):

You can preprocess your file before handing it off to pandas.

```
with open('yourfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip().rsplit(',', number_of_columns - 1) for line in f]

# if your csv has column names on the first row
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=data[0], data=data[1:])
```

This solution only works if the only extra commas are in the first column of data.

Comment: Many thanks! It gives me the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'maxsplit'

Comment: @datazang: Sorry, I wrote `maxsplit` when I meant `rsplit`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I define the 'number_of_columns' since it says it is not defined?

Comment: @datazang: You actually need to provide a number.  How many columns is your csv supposed to have? You could define it on a previous line `number_of_columns = 18 #or whatever` or hardcode it `rsplit(',', 18 - 1)`

Comment: There should be 42 columns.

Comment: Omg, sorry again... It now gives another error: AssertionError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 42 columns. 

I have no idea about what I am making wrong. :)

Comment: hmm... see if this works `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data[1:],columns=data[0])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244521/discussion-between-datazang-and-steven-rumbalski).

Comment: It gives the same error, unfortunately. # GH#26429 do not raise user-facing AssertionError

ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 42 columns